# Adding a class to all elements within a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm having a for loop to get a certain task done.Now in that for loop,in the last iteration, I need to add the `green-color` class to all the elements which has the class `checkMarks`.

This is my code, currently it adds the `green-color` class only to the first element. Is there a way to do this without having to use another for loop inside the current for loop?

```
const studentLength = 24;
for(let i=0; i<studentLength; i++){
   //something happens here

   if(i===studentLength ){ //if last iteration 
       document.querySelectorAll(".checkMarks").classList.add("green-color");
   }
}
```

Comment: No, `querySelectorAll` returns a static NodeList, and you have to iterate over the items on that list, if you want to do something for each single one of them. (If you don’t want to do that - then work with a different structure, if possible. One single class applied to the container element could also apply the same formatting to _all_ `.checkMarks`, you just need to create an appropriate rule in your stylesheet.)

Comment: @CBroe Cool.That's a nice suggestion.Tanks +1

Comment: why do you so it only in the last iteration of your loop? why not move it after the loop?

Comment: @Pete Beautiful!!!! simple & on the spot!! best answer :) thanks +1

Comment: I assume the students who pass, get class checkMarks - why not EITHER add color:green to that class OR ALSO add that class where you add the checkMarks class?

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the suggestion.This is to enable certain facilities based on the final iteration score. So doing at the end of the for loop is a must. :)

Comment: With stating "for(let i=0; i<studentLength; i++){" you might never reach "(i===studentLength )". You would need "i<=studentLengt". Just my two cents ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop since the All in querySelectorAll returns a nodelist, but you should use forEach on the students too
I wrap in a spread [...] to handle early EDGE browsers

```
students.forEach(student => { /*something happens here */});
[...document.querySelectorAll(".checkMarks")].forEach(chk => chk.classList.add("green-color"));
```

If there is only ONE checkMark you can do `document.querySelector(".checkMarks").classList.add("green-color")` without the `all`, but vanilla JS does not support adding to a list in one go like the equivalent jQuery  `$(".checkMarks").addClass("green-color")` would

Comment: Cool, thanks! :) I prefer @pete's answer (comment section).

Comment: That is what I do. Move it after the loop.

Comment: I see. Is it required to use the second `.forEach`? If it's out of the loop, isn't this suffice?`document.querySelectorAll(".checkMarks").classList.add("green-color")`

Comment: No. It is not jQuery. Vanilla querySelectorAll returns a nodelist so you MUST loop

Comment: If there is only ONE checkMark you can do `document.querySelector(".checkMarks").classList.add("green-color")` without the all

Comment: I see.Thanks for clarifying that! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate the result of `querySelectorAll` and apply the class to each element:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".checkMarks").forEach(e => e.classList.add("green-color"));
```

```css
.green-color {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkMarks">TEST</div>
<div class="checkMarks">TEST2</div>
<div class="checkMarks">TEST3</div>
<div class="checkMarks">TEST4</div>
<div class="checkMarks">TEST5</div>
<div class="checkMarks">TEST6</div>
<div class="checkMarks">TEST7</div>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! :) I prefer @pete's answer (comment section).

Comment: That is what this answer is doing, also. You'll notice I removed all references to the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a `for...of` loop (ES6):

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".checkMarks");
for (const div of divs) {
  div.classList.add("green-color");
}
```

```css
.green-color {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkMarks">DIV1</div>
<div class="checkMarks">DIV2</div>
<div class="checkMarks">DIV3</div>
<div class="checkMarks">DIV4</div>
<div class="checkMarks">DIV5</div>
<div class="checkMarks">DIV6</div>
<div class="checkMarks">DIV7</div>
```